# C# Rest Api Cleaning results of long running operations in database

Tags: c#, rest, long-running-processes

I'm planning to use the so called long running tasks.
I have read best practice articles, and will implement different endpoints for starting, getting status and result of such operations.
Such long running operations will include sql procedures, storing results in tables according to operation Id.
The question is - in what moment should I clear the result, dropping unnecessary data from DB?
I will implement endpont to clear result gracefully, but what if the user simply closes the web page?
Should I implement background service cleaning results by timer?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Long running tasks shouldn't be implemented within a web service. Implementing a separate background service is a right solution.

Comment: Yes, y're absolutely right, I'll use a separate backround service or use rabbit mq. I'm a novice in some things. But still, when should I clear the unnecessary data, if the user closes the web page? A have two approaches - implementing cleaning background service, scheduling by a timer, or clearing data on the next time user loggs in.

Comment: It's completely up to you and business requirements when to clean them up. If the data is sensitive then it should be cleaned as soon as possible, if not - any reasonable moment is suffice.